# twig: find out if I'm in a subroute of a mainroute

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to exclude a menu if I'm in a subroute of a mainroute.

So for example this:

```
if route is /backend/* then exclude
else if route is /backend/admin/* don't exlude
else if route is /backend/admin/create then exclude
```

Is there a way to achieve this in twig with a few lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get current path in twig you can use `app.request.pathinfo`.

**Edit:**

If you want to get route name of current url you can do it in following way.

Add `Router` object as template global variable.

```
#In app/config.yml
#.......

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    globals:
      router: @router
```

And then in your template,

```
{% set route_info = router.match(app.request.pathinfo) %}
{% set route_name = route_info._router %}
```

Then you can include/exclude your template based on route name.

**Edit Again**

Route name can be found in much simpler way.

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}
```